# Team Foundation Explorer - Check In for the First Time

Tags: .net, tfs

How do you check in code for the first time in Team Foundation Server?

I created a local path, dropped some code in it, now what? Hitting refresh doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to right-click on the solution in your project explorer and select "Add project to source control". Then it will walk you through the process of adding it to TFS.

Comment: +1 That worked great! Thanks. Now, hypothetically, lets say I have some Ruby files in a separate folder (not a project) how would I check those in?

Comment: Another poster mentioned it, but in the Source Control viewer in Visual Studio, there are "Add files" and "Add folders" buttons on the toolbar that let you add files that aren't part of a project.

If you don't have VS, another option is http://www.teamprise.com

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add files to source control without using a solution, then you need to actually add them to TFS.  TFS will only show the files it knows about in source control.

In the Source Control Explorer window there should be an add file button.  You can hit that and use it to add files/folders to source control.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest you install the latest edition of Power Tools for TFS - which includes the Windows Explorer Shell (you need to select custom install for that).  This will add a context menu in Windows Explorer for directories that are mapped to a Workspace - so you won't have to start Visual Studio to do simple file manipulation like this.

The download is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx

Comment: +1 - You, sir, are my hero.  I've wanted something like TFS/explorer integration for a while now.  Thanks!